# How to fix IIS locally deployed application keeps loading on browser when visited?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have problem deploying on Local IIS in a MS Server 2019 Data Center machine,
my application is currently is targeting .NET6.0
and my machine has sdks for both .NET6.0 and .NET7 (which is installed by latest VStudio)
Also installed NET6 Hosting Bundle and NET7 Hosting Bundle (just to be safe)

I tried every .NET Clr Version that is available on the IIS Pool Application configuration,
but when I click browse it just keeps on loading.

Physical folder is also already shared to IIS_IUSRS and also tried IISRESET but nothing works.

Comment: Please run a report to rule out common issues first, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Comment: You need needs more information to analyze and reproduce the problem, you can check the console or Event Viewer for related error messages.